# Get text data from a pdf with python

Tags: python, nlp, pdf-scraping

I am stuck with how to deal with pdfs here. I dont know how to scrape directly from the web, and when I download locally they are complete nonsense, not the actual text data.

I have tried to download with requests but the contents is then just useless.

```
import PyPDF2
#  textract
import requests
# from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
# from nltk.corpus import stopwords


def get_amount(url):
  data = requests.get(url)
  with open('/Users/derricdonehoo/code/derric-d/price-processor/exmpl.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data.content)
```

I am trying to figure out how to get data from a pdf. Any suggestons would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What output do you get when you scrape a PDF? "the contents is then just useless" doesn't help.

Comment: Can you provide the link of the sample file.

Comment: @blackbrandt i think it gives me just a binary file or something, whatever is the base of a pdf file

Comment: sorry @AshwinGeetD'Sa the file is confidential.

Comment: ```
import PyPDF2;
pdf_file = open('sample.pdf');
read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file);
number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages();
page = read_pdf.getPage(0);
page_content = page.extractText();
print page_content;
```

Comment: Try to use the code similar to the one above, it may work if the encoding of your file is a suitable one

Comment: ah i understand, that does work.. i had made some stupid assumptions before.

Comment: thanks @AshwinGeetD'Sa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please modify to below:

```
import PyPDF2
pdf_file = open('/Users/derricdonehoo/code/derric-d/price-processor/exmpl.pdf')
read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
for i in number_of_pages:
    page = read_pdf.getPage(0)
    page_content = page.extractText()
    print page_content
```